# Firebase cloud function always fails - onerror

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to call firebase cloud function using xmlhttprequest through serve feature([testing locally](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator)), the following code is xmlHttpRequest

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onload = function() {
    //success
};
req.onerror = function() {
    //always fall to this function
};
var url = 'https://us-central1-' + getFirebaseProjectId() + '.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld';
req.open('GET', url);

//Chrome does not allow 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' from 
//localhost:5000 (non-google server)

//I am using mozilla firefox with 'serve' feature, hope 
//this solve 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' problem

req.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
req.send();
```

I can see that cloud function is executed successfully in firebase console. But i am always fall into onerror function.

I also enabled CORS in cloud functions by

```
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
```

While hosting functions locally i get following error

[image]
After research of two day of research ,

- Updated node and firebase to compatible version.
- Cleared cache
- Updated firebase-tools, firebase functions through npm

. Still not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Delete the project, re-initialize the project with `firebase init function`. hope this helps.